# HDMI Output to VGA Input

Tags: conversion, input, vga, hdmi

I have a computer with only an HDMI output and a monitor with only a VGA input. I would like to have the computer extend its display onto the monitor.

However, I have read that VGA outs cannot be converted to HDMI ins, but have seen nothing that implies the opposite. And logically, I would think that a higher def technology (HDMI) should be convertible to a lower def technology (VGA).

1. Is this setup possible?
2. If yes to 1, what do you recommend I use to connect them?

   - Will a simple [cable like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YTJSNEI) work?
   - Or do I need an HDMI to VGA [converter like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003O55U8K)?
   - Or would I, for some strange reason, need a VGA to HDMI [converter like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K4W62R4)?

Answer (score 4):

VGA to HDMI converters are very common, someone lied to you. As for your HDMI to VGA, 1 needs to be supported by your video card, 2 is what you need (ymmv, but the amazon comments look good), 3 is a VGA to HDMI, opposite of what you want.

Alternatively, spend a couple of bucks and upgrade to a newer monitor. Get in this century.

Comment: Lie is maybe a too strong word here, because you don't know the exact circumstances, I suggest to make it nicer. (Btw, your answer is enough good for an up.)

Answer (score 2):

You need a converter like the one you linked to at option 2. HDMI is digital signal which should be converted to analog VGA signal using a DAC [like this](http://www.chrontel.com/media/Datasheets/CH7101A%20Brief%20Datasheet%20Rev0.6.pdf) which is supposed to be embedded in such converters. Simple wiring won't do the trick.