# How to connect 2 monitors to a laptop

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors

I want to extend the Windows desktop on my laptop onto two external monitors (total of three separate desktop displays), as shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ei58JE63jcw

In that video, the laptop had a VGA output and USB ports.  The author connected one VGA monitor to the VGA port and used a USB to VGA adapter to connect the other monitor.

I have two VGA monitors, but the laptop's only video output is an HDMI port.
I tried to replicate the setup in the video using an HDMI to VGA splitter and a USB 3.0 to VGA adapter.  It didn't work.

The laptop is an HP Envy K203TX, which has Nvidia GTX 850m graphics.  How can I connect my two VGA monitors to the laptop given the laptop's available ports?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do HDMI to VGA cables actually work as advertised?](http://superuser.com/questions/1037748/do-hdmi-to-vga-cables-actually-work-as-advertised) OR http://superuser.com/questions/332124/will-an-hdmi-to-vga-connector-work OR http://superuser.com/questions/76497/hdmi-to-vga-convert OR http://superuser.com/questions/954837/hdmi-output-to-vga-input OR http://superuser.com/questions/225721/how-can-i-plug-my-hdmi-device-into-a-vga-input OR http://superuser.com/questions/501222/are-hdmi-to-vga-adapters-really-device-specific

Comment: Is your goal to mirror the same display as the laptop on both monitors, have one monitor match the laptop and one display different content, have both monitors display matching content that's different from the laptop, or have three different contents displayed?

Comment: @Dave, none of the proposed duplicates addresses what's asked in the question.  The question is about how to connect two monitors using some combination of available ports and whatever adapters will do it.  Whether or not HDMI to VGA works is tangential to one potential option.

Comment: @fixer1234
What I want to do is :- Extend my laptop display on both the monitors. Something like this :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ei58JE63jcw

Comment: Was the USB to VGA adapter an active convertor (containing some circuitry), like the one in the video and did that piece work?  I suspect your HDMI-VGA splitter was a scam.  Converting HDMI to VGA requires active circuitry.  It would be helpful to add the laptop model to the question.  Its video card has to support three displays, you need working adapters, and they need Windows 10 drivers.

Comment: @fixer1234
It wasn't an active converter I think. My Laptop is HP Envy k203 TX.